# if-statement with continue or break

Tags: java, if-statement, break, continue

I'm doing the simulation of Java OCA test. During my study with the book "OCA - Study Guide" (Sybex), at the second chapter there is the following (Table 2.5, page 91):

if - allows break statement:    NO

if - allows continue statement: NO

But during the simulation of Java OCA test, did by Sybex (online book OCA), there is this question:

```
int  x= 5;
    while (x>=0) {
        int y = 3;
        while (y>0) {
            if (x<2)
                continue;
            x--; y--;
            System.out.println(x*y + " ");
        }
    }
```

My answer was: It doesn't compile
But the correct answer is: 
8 
3 
0 
2

What is the correct information? 
What is right (book or simulation test)?

This is the table:

[image: Table 2.5 - page 91 - OCA Java book]

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why wouldn't it compile? It's not clear what's meant by "if - allows break statement: No". Yes, you can conditionally break/continue. You must be misinterpreting what the book is saying, or it's an awful book.

Comment: The study guide probably means that an `if` on its own can't contain `continue` or `break`. It needs an enclosing `for/while/switch`.

Comment: In this case the `continue` belongs to the enclosing `while`-loop, not to the `if`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I tried with an if-statempent without while-loop and it doesn't compile.

Comment: if this scan is really from book, agree with @Carcigenicate throw into trash

Comment: The book is an awful book, too much errata: https://www.selikoff.net/java-oca-8-programmer-i-study-guide/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you need to understand is that in your code, the `if` statement is INSIDE a while loop (which is inside another while loop) and that's why it's OK to use `continue` in that case. An `if` statement outside of a loop isn't allowed to use `continue`. But inside of a for loop, while loop or do while loop, you CAN use continue inside an `if` statement.

So the code that you provided works and the output is:

```
8 
3 
0 
2
```

But then I took your code and commented out the two while loops and now the code doesn't compile:

```
        int  x= 5;
//      while (x>=0) {
            int y = 3;
//          while (y>0) {
                if (x<2)
                    continue; //<-- COMPILE ERROR: continue cannot be used outside of a loop
                x--; y--;
                System.out.println(x*y + " ");
//          }
//      }
```

The output is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    continue cannot be used outside of a loop
```

I wrote a very detailed [Java looping tutorial](https://funnelgarden.com/java-for-loop/) that covers the [continue statement](https://funnelgarden.com/java-for-loop/#Continue_Statement), the [break statement](https://funnelgarden.com/java-for-loop/#Break_Statement), and all the different types of loops in Java.

Answer (score 0):

i think continue here is following the outer while loop not immediate if  , since continue is allowed inside while loop it works.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   int  x= 5;
 //while (x>=0) {
   int y = 3;
 //while (y>0) {
     if (x<2)
     continue;
     x--; y--;
      System.out.println(x*y + " ");
       }
      }
    // }
  // }

Error:(10, 21) java: continue outside of loop
```

Comment: I didnt get you,why its terrible way ?

Comment: by clicking in editor and not reading/understanding good literature

Comment: Thanks for judging but clicking in editor gives me better understanding as i can debug the program and actually understand it in better way than just reading someone's analysis, that does not mean i don't read/understand good literature.

Answer (score 0):

Both book and test simulators are right. `break` and `continue` keywords are not allowed inside `if`. The `continue` you see inside `if` is perfectly valid because it appears within the context of outer `while` so that's fine. To wrap it all, when you start a `while` or `for` block, using `break` and `continue` everywhere inside this block is correct, even if it happens to be inside an `if` block.

Answer (score -1):

normally **break** and **continue** are allowed in if statements but you should not use them that often because it is bad Coding stlye.

*unit = unit test framework

A Reason would be for example: If you try to test your software with unit (if you dont know unit not yet dont worry :D) it is much harder to understand what the code does than normally and also to test the code.

Good Luck and have fun hope i can help you